# Determine the area of ​​the shape bounded by the curves

Tags: derivatives, area, curves

$$y=x^2 + 1, x=2, x=1, y=0$$

I've got exam today and I'm learning how to solve this type of task. The exam is about derivations mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw the curves roughly on a graph, you'll see that the required area is just the area under the curve $y=x^2+1$ between certain limits. Integrate $y=x^2+1$ between those limits.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case we want to integrate instead of taking the derivative.

Drawing the picture we get

[image: ints]

To find the area under the curve, all we have to do is integrate - so we get

$$A=\int\limits_1^2(x^2+1)-0\,dx=\int\limits_1^2x^2+1\,dx=\frac{1}{3}x^3+x\bigg|_{x=1}^{x=2}=\frac{8}{3}+2-\frac{1}{3}-1=\frac{10}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_1^2 x^2+1 \mathrm{d}x = \left[\frac{x^3}{3}+x\right]_1^2=\frac{10}{3}
$$

Comment: Adding some explanation about how one "sets up" the integral would likely be more helpful than doing the integration to the person who posted this Question.

Comment: Doing the integration can help him to understand by himself.